# Runtime Error of meteor/accounts-base

Tags: angular, meteor, ionic-framework

After adding

> function requestPhoneVerification(phoneNumber: string, callback?:Function):void;
>
> function verifyPhone(phoneNumber: string, code:string, callback?: Function): void;

in meteor.d.ts runtime error of "meteor/accounts-base" occur

> Error: Cannot find module "meteor/accounts-base"
>   at webpackMissingModule (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:548:87)
>   at Object.214 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:548:184) at
>   webpack_require (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30) at
>   Object.151 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:65:15) at
>   webpack_require (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30) at
>   Object.685 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1121:17) at
>   webpack_require (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30) at

Comment: It worked before adding those two lines of code? Also, does this package exist in the first place? https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-base

Comment: yes, it worked before adding these two lines of code

Comment: Where have you added the above two lines. Can you post some actual code here.

Comment: I added these two lines in meteor.d.ts file